# escaping complicated command line arguments in bash and ssh

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ssh

I am working on a bash script to retrieve uptime of a list of servers.  It just reads from a file and executes a remote command on the server.  Some servers may have been up for a long time while some may have just been rebooted.  I was using something very simple:

```
uptime | awk '{print \$2,\$3,\$4}'
```

This works if the server has been up for at least a day, but if it's been up only for a few hours the output from uptime doesn't include the work days, and just uses an hour:minute format.

I found something that I quite like, but can't seem to escape it properly in the ssh command, let alone trying to pass it in the bash script:

```
uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if ($7=="min") m=$6; else {if ($7~/^day/) {d=$6;h=$8;m=$9} else {h=$6;m=$7}}} {print d+0,"days,",h+0,"hours,",m+0,"minutes."}'
```

I have tried several things, but this to me should work and can't seem to figure out what I am missing:

```
ssh user@IP "uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if (\$7==\"min\") m=\$6; else {if (\$7\~\/^day\/) {d=\$6;h=\$8;m=\$9} else {h=\$6;m=\$7}}} {print d+0,\"days,\",h+0,\"hours,\",m+0,\"minutes.\"}'"
```

The output I get is:

```
awk: {d=h=m=0; if ($7=="min") m=$6; else {if ($7\~\/^day\/) {d=$6;h=$8;m=$9} else {h=$6;m=$7}}} {print d+0,"days,",h+0,"hours,",m+0,"minutes."}
awk:                                            ^ backslash not last character on line
```

In the end I am trying to put this in a bash script that is something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r server; do
    ssh -tt user@$server  "uptime command" < /dev/null >> /home/user/uptime
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just send the commands to the standard input of ssh:

```
cat <<'EOF' | ssh user@machine
uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if ($7=="min") m=$6; else {if ($7~/^day/) {d=$6;h=$8;m=$9} else {h=$6;m=$7}}} {print d+0,"days,",h+0,"hours,",m+0,"minutes."}'
EOF
```

Comment: Yes, heredoc is the way to go. See Example 19-7 in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Comment: This is an interesting approach and it does work on its own in bash, but I was having trouble integrating it into what I was already using, since I was running this against a list of servers.  I will have more time to work on this later and take another look.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider You can save the command in a variable and then run it against your list of servers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're escaping too much:

```
ssh user@IP "uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if (\$7==\"min\") m=\$6; else {if (\$7~/^day/) {d=\$6;h=\$8;m=\$9} else {h=\$6;m=\$7}}} {print d+0,\"days,\",h+0,\"hours,\",m+0,\"minutes.\"}'"
```

I get:

```
6 days, 11 hours, 21 minutes.
```

---

**Update:**

Since the same command is meant to be sent to more than one different remote host, I recommend saving it to a variable for easy reuse.

```
command="uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if (\$7==\"min\") m=\$6; else {if (\$7~/^day/) {d=\$6;h=\$8;m=\$9} else {h=\$6;m=\$7}}} {print d+0,\"days,\",h+0,\"hours,\",m+0,\"minutes.\"}'"
ssh user@IP1 "$command"
ssh user@IP2 "$command"
```

Test run:

```
$ bash script.sh
0 days, 2 hours, 26 minutes.
7 days, 4 hours, 18 minutes.
```

**Wait, there's more:**

I often need to send *multiple* commands to the remote hosts: for this I find the [quoted heredoc syntax](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), suggested by [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56669959/7659430), to be most handy.

```
command=$(cat <<'EOF'
hostname
uptime | awk -F'( |,|:)+' '{d=h=m=0; if ($7=="min") m=$6; else {if ($7~/^day/) {d=$6;h=$8;m=$9} else {h=$6;m=$7}}} {print d+0,"days,",h+0,"hours,",m+0,"minutes."}'
EOF
)
ssh user@IP1 "$command"
ssh user@IP2 "$command"
```

This is the output:

```
$ bash script.sh
server1
0 days, 2 hours, 26 minutes.
server2
7 days, 4 hours, 18 minutes.
```

Comment: Thank you.  This allowed me to integrate it into my existing bash script and works fine!

Comment: i actually mention in my initial post that i already had a script i was using and trying to integrate it, so i don't know if "it emerges" is accurate, but i really appreciate the different ways of doing this, it is helping me learn bash!

Comment: @chrisschneider You're totally right, I'm going to correct this.